# How should one decide how many and which nodes to select in the quorum set when configuring a Stellar Core Node

Tags: stellar-core, scp, validators, protocol

How should one decide how many and which nodes to select in the quorum set when configuring a Stellar Core Node (in archiver mode)?
There is a list of validators in the link below, should all or some of these be used  in the stellar-core.cfg file? And what should determine which of the validators should be in quorum subsets and the different `THRESHOLD_PERCENT` values that should be set?

Thanks for any help.

https://github.com/stellar/docs/blob/master/validators.md